# Missing 770201 seconds in Y2K2038

Tags: real-time

From what I understand about the Y2K38 problem, unpatched 32 bit systems with signed UTC times will jump back from 19 January 2038 at 03:14:07 UTC to 13 December 1901, at 20:45:52. Calculating the difference between these date-times gives me 4294197095 seconds. That's not the same as 4294967296 seconds, off by 770201 seconds. That's 8 days, 21 hours, 56 minutes and 41 seconds.

I could imagine 2 hours, 3 minutes and 19 seconds of smear seconds. But then that leaves 9 days. Where did the time go?

(If this fits better on a different stackexchange site, please let me know which.)

Comment: $2^{32}=4294967296$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks, corrected... ( I hope, I'm on phone...)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an error in your math. 19 January 2038 at 03:14:07 UTC is $t_1 = 2147483647$ seconds after the epoch. 13 December 1901 at 20:45:52 is $t_2 = 2147483648$ seconds before the epoch.

Notice that $t_1 = 2^{31}-1$ and that $ - t_2 = -2^{31}$. That's exactly the minimum and maximum values representable by a signed 32-bit integer in two's complement. Unsurprisingly: $t_1 - (-t_2) = 2^{32}-1$, as expected.

```
$ t1=$(date -d "2038-1-19 03:14:07+00:00" +%s)
$ t2=$(date -d "1901-12-13 20:45:52+00:00" +%s)
$ echo "t1: $t1; t2: $t2; Difference: $(( $t1 - $t2 ))"
t1: 2147483647; t2: -2147483648; Difference: 4294967295
```